# Google APIs Client Library for Javascript and Offline Web Applications

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html5-appcache

My web application uses the Google APIs Client Library for Javascript https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/.

I would like to make the application usable in offline mode as well. It is clear that I cannot  make any API calls while the document is in offline mode, but I am wondering what to do with the following step

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>,
```

which is the first step in setting up the library. Does this step work in offline mode? And is it safe to cache the client.js file in the applications appcache (that is to include it in its manifest)?

So far, I haven't found any worked-out example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am using requireJS and HTML5 appcache with google JS API for auth and contacts in my application. If you put the file in appcache manifest. It does work well when offline.

I am guessing that it should work with normal caching too. Just that caching should have been enabled for the file (read necessary headers sent), and file should have been cached .